# How to extract string between " " in R?

Tags: r, string, gsub

How to extract data between strings "".

I have following string data as example:

```
x <- c('"Apr 21 2020 16:45        10894 <A HREF=\"D188_2020-03-30.csv\">D188_2020-03-30.csv</A>"')
```

would like to extract `D188_2020-03-30.csv\` as a output.

Have refer various `gsub`  example but unable to figure out.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple strings between `""`, so you need some another identifier to extract what you want. Maybe try string between `""` after `"HREF"`.

```
sub('.*HREF="(.*?)".*', '\\1', x)
#[1] "D188_2020-03-30.csv"
```

Comment: Yes tried ...perfectly working...! thanks @Ronak..awesome...!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative using the `str_extract` function from the `stringr` package.

```
str_extract(string = x, pattern = ("(?<=HREF=\").*(?=.>D188)"))
```

This basically returns the text by looking behind to match `(?<=HREF=\")` and looking ahead to match `(?=.>D188)")` .

```
# [1] "D188_2020-03-30.csv"
```